# Grouping inner loop and limit

Tags: mysql, sql

I was not sure what to title this question exactly

I got the following columns in a table

```
id, slug, date, market
```

each row is a date, coin name, and market cap.

I am grouping by date

```
SELECT slug, date, market
from coin
order by date asc, market desc

slug        date        market
bitcoin     2013-04-28  1500520000
litecoin    2013-04-28  73773400
peercoin    2013-04-28  7255800
namecoin    2013-04-28  5969080
terracoin   2013-04-28  1510150
novacoin    2013-04-28  1155160
bitcoin     2013-04-29  1491160000 -- new date
litecoin    2013-04-29  74952700
peercoin    2013-04-29  7262850
namecoin    2013-04-29  5977460
terracoin   2013-04-29  1508860
novacoin    2013-04-29  1162460
bitcoin     2013-04-30  1597780000 -- new date
litecoin    2013-04-30  75726800
peercoin    2013-04-30  7641700
namecoin    2013-04-30  7185910
terracoin   2013-04-30  1650870
novacoin    2013-04-30  1249450
bitcoin     2013-05-01  1542820000 -- new date
litecoin    2013-05-01  73901200
```

I want to add up the market for each date but I only want to include the top 3 rows by market per date. Ultimately I want the data to look like this

```
date        total market     
29/04/2013  1573375550 -- (1500520000 + 73773400 + 7255800)
30/04/2013  1681148500
01/05/2013  1616721200
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think variables are the simplest way to enumerate the rows for the filtering:

```
select date, sum(market)
from (select c.*,
             (@rn := if(@d = date, @rn + 1,
                        if(@d := date, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from coin c cross join
           (select @d := '', @rn := 0) params
      order by date, market desc
     ) c
where rn <= 3
group by date;
```

Comments:

- In MySQL, 8.0+, you would use `row_number()` instead of variables.
- In the latest versions of MySQL 5.7, you might need to do the sort by `date, market desc` in an addition subquery.

Comment: thanks a lot this what I needed but would have never figured it out  my sql knowledge is basic

Answer (score 0):

You cloud use a group by date and limit by 3 (then revert the result for obtain the result as you showed )

```
  select * from (

  select date, sum(market)
  from your_table
  group by date 
  order by date desc limit 3
) t
order by t.date asc
```

Comment: This only returns 3 rows not as many as I have distinct dates

Comment: In your sample you return 3 date ... expalin better  .. or provide a clear  sample  for result